# visreg visualization of mgcv results (GAM)

Tags: r, data-visualization, random-effects-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I fitted a GAM with random effects using mgcv, and I've noticed that the visualization of the smooths using visreg does not appear to match the output of mgcv's plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(visreg)
library(mgcv)

fit <- gam(log(Response) ~ s(Tag, by=Wundinfektionsstatus) + s(PatientenID, bs = "re") + s(PatientenID, Tag, bs = "re"), data=zeitreihen, method="REML")

intercept <- fit$coefficients[["(Intercept)"]]

plot(fit, trans = exp, shift = intercept, shade=T, residuals=T, select=1)
plot(fit, trans = exp, shift = intercept, shade=T, residuals=T, select=2)

visreg(fit, "Tag", "Wundinfektionsstatus", gg=T, type="conditional", overlay=T, partial=F, rug=F, ylab="Response", trans=exp)
```

[image: First smooth]
[image: Second smooth]
[image: visreg output]

The first two plots match the data pretty well, specifically the constant decrease in the second plot. Note that in the visreg plot, that curve appears almost constant with a sharp uptick at the end, and the height of the first maximum does not match.

Any ideas how this disconnect comes about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference arises because you are ignoring the intercept (& the coef for the non-reference levels of the factor; see first Note) when you go via the `mgcv:::plot.gam()` method. The *visreg* output is showing the smooth effect of each variable **conditional** upon the other terms in the model. The blue line shows the estimated smooth effect of `Tag`, including the model intercept.

**Note** your model may be wrong; you probably should include `Wundinfektionsstatus` as the by-factor smooths are centered about zero and hence you need a parametric fixed effect (in this case) to raise adjust the mean response of each level up/down. Without it, the model has to build this into the smooth functions.

You can achieve the same thing in *mgcv* by predicting from the model over a grid of values for `Tag` (in this case of the blue line) repeated for each level of your factor and you'll need to include a dummy patient ID, which we'll exclude:

```
## Assuming data in df
pred_df <- with(df, expand.grid(Tag = seq(min(Tag), max(Tag), length = 100),
                                Wundinfektionsstatus = levels(Wundinfektionsstatus),
                                PatientenID = sample(PatientenID, 1)))

pred <- predict(fit, newdata = pred_df, type = 'link', se.fit = TRUE,
                exclude = c("s(PatientenID)", "s(PatientenID,Tag)"))
pred_df <- cbind(pred_df, as.data.frame(pred))

## create confidence interval and back transform
pred_df <- transform(pred_df,
                     fitted_response = exp(fit),
                     fitted_upper    = exp(fit + (2 * se.fit)),
                     fitted_lower    = exp(fit - (2 * se.fit)))
```

`pred_df` should be in a format to plot with *ggplot2* as you see fit:

```
library('ggplot2')

ggplot(pred_df, aes(x = Tag, y = fitted_response)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(fill = Wundinfektionsstatus, ymin = fitted_lower,
                  ymax = fitted_upper)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Wundinfektionsstatus))
```

**Note**: thread the above as pseudo-code as I wrote this from memory and it is untested as there wasn't a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks, and good catch about the level-wise intercept! I've tried your code, and it seems to work somewhat, however, depending on which patient is sampled, the results vary drastically (the first bump in the blue curve appears anywhere between 120 and  300). I suspect that your approach includes the random effects per patient, but I am interested in plotting the main, fixed effects.

Comment: Got it, this seems to do the trick: pred <- predict(fit, newdata = pred_df, type = 'response', se.fit = TRUE, exclude=c(s(PatientenID, bs = "re"), s(PatientenID, Tag, bs = "re")))

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to use the `exclude` argument to drop the random effects, despite referring to it. And yes, that's what I was going to do (your second comment)

Comment: However, this, `exclude = c("s(PatientenID)", "s(PatientenID,Tag)")` would be what I would have expected would be required. You should name the smooths here as they appear in the table of smooths you get from `summary(model)`

Comment: Good idea, and thanks for your help!