# visreg visualization of GAM results (mgcv package)

Tags: r, data-visualization, random-effects-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

How do I plot the generalised additive model using visreg? I have tried with the following code but it does not work and I am unsure how to specify it correctly. I have looked at [visreg visualization of mgcv results (GAM)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425194/visreg-visualization-of-mgcv-results-gam) but am unable to replicate it. I would like to produce plots for both random effects I've specified. Could someone point me in the right direction?

My code:

```
mod = gam(Secondary_yes ~ s(Year) + s(Region, bs = "re") + LocSub + s(Primary, bs = "re"), data = df , family = binomial, method = "REML")

visreg(gam, "Year", by="Proportion", main="Plot", gg = T)
```

Model summary:

```
Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
Secondary_yes ~ s(Year) + s(Region, bs = "re") + LocSub + 
    s(Primary, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        -2.2682     0.5081  -4.464 8.05e-06 ***
LocSubSubstantive   0.8329     0.3031   2.748    0.006 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
             edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
s(Year)    2.229   2.78   3.16    0.314    
s(Region)  8.282  13.00  38.92 5.26e-05 ***
s(Primary) 8.105   9.00 166.46  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.208   Deviance explained =   20%
-REML = 518.17  Scale est. = 1         n = 1141
```

Dataframe:

```
 $ Month        : num [1:1141] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Year         : num [1:1141] 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 ...
 $ Primary      : Factor w/ 10 levels "Foot & Ankle",..: 10 10 7 8 8 9 9 7 3 1 ...
 $ LocSub       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Locum","Substantive": 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Region       : Factor w/ 14 levels "East Midlands",..: 8 11 5 2 2 8 8 2 8 8 ...
 $ Secondary_yes: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Thank you for any help!