# GAM partial effect line does not overlap raw data?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am using a GAM to model the relationship between a response (`mean_NN_dist`) and a predictor (`spRichness`), while incorporating the spatial structure of the dataset (`x` and `y`).

My goal is to plot the partial effect of the main predictor, while holding the spatial predictor constant, as a way of "accounting for" spatial autocorrelation.

I fit a GAM using the `bam()` function, as this is a relatively large dataset.

```r
gamFit <- bam(mean_NN_dist ~ s(spRichness) + s(x, y, k = 1000, 
              bs = 'gp', m = 2), data = cellDF, gamma = 1.4, 
              method = 'fREML')
```

And for comparison, I fit another model that does not explicitly include the spatial structure.

```r
gamFit2 <- bam(mean_NN_dist ~ s(spRichness), data = cellDF, 
               gamma = 1.4, method = 'fREML')
```

I use the `visreg` package to plot the partial effect plot. I plot on the response scale so that I can plot the GAM fitted line in the same plot as the raw data.

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))

visreg(gamFit, 'spRichness', scale = 'response', ylim = c(0, 0.20))
points(jitter(cellDF$spRichness), cellDF$mean_NN_dist, 
        col = adjustcolor('gray70', alpha.f = 0.5))

visreg(gamFit2, 'spRichness', scale = 'response', ylim = c(0, 0.20))
points(jitter(cellDF$spRichness), cellDF$mean_NN_dist, 
        col = adjustcolor('gray70', alpha.f = 0.5))
```

[image]

What I find confusing is that with the model plotted on the left, which includes the spatial predictor, the fitted line does not overlap the raw data, whereas it does for the other model that does not include the spatial coordinates.

Is this a sign that I am not going about this properly, or is this potentially reasonable, given that this is a partial effects plot?

It might be helpful to know that most of the values in the dataset are for lower values of spRichness, and there are relatively few observations for higher values.

```r
> table(cellDF$spRichness)

   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12 
 967 1790 1810 1223 1129  528  250  185   44   25    6
```

Advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

Following up on a comment below, here is a plot of the raw data against the predicted response under the GAM.

```r
> plot(cellDF$mean_NN_dist, predict(gamFit))
> abline(0, 1, col='red')
```

[image]

This may have to do with `visreg` R package, and how it is handling this GAM. If I do the following, this issue goes away.

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot.gam(gamFit, seWithMean = TRUE, select = 1, 
          shift = coef(gamFit)[1], shade = TRUE, 
          shade.col = 'light blue', ylim = c(0, 0.2))
points(jitter(cellDF$spRichness), cellDF$mean_NN_dist, 
         col = adjustcolor('gray70', alpha.f = 0.5))
plot.gam(gamFit2, seWithMean = TRUE, select = 1, 
         shift = coef(gamFit2)[1], shade = TRUE, 
         shade.col = 'light blue', ylim = c(0, 0.2))
points(jitter(cellDF$spRichness), cellDF$mean_NN_dist, 
         col = adjustcolor('gray70', alpha.f = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like `visreg` is fixing the value of the spatial smoother at some value (maybe the mean of x,y?). [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425194/visreg-visualization-of-mgcv-results-gam) post looks like it's dealing with similar things. 

To make sure that the predictions are different from the data, it might be helpful to run: `plot(cellDF$mean_NN_dist,predict(gamFit)); abline(0,1,col='red')`. This will give you an idea of whether the problem comes from `gam`/`bam` or `visreg`

Comment: Thanks @S.Robinson for the suggestion. See my edit. I'm looking into the post you linked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you forgot about the spatial component; you didn't tell `visreg` what covariate values to use for the spatial locations so it will have gone with a default which might be the mean of each spatial coordinate. If they happen to be in a place with higher counts, that would shift the plot up. The second model doesn't have a spatial component so there's nothing to condition on in this plot so the fit does go through the data as you would expect.

The reason `plot.gam` is producing what you want is because this is showing a partial effect which you then shift by adding on the intercept. This is basically ignoring the spatial component in the first model (it's contribution is being set to 0) which is what you also get if you exclude this spatial term from the model.

You can proceed to do what you want but visreg style without conditioning the predictions on particular values of the x and y coordinates with:

```r
newdf <- with(cellDF,
              data.frame(sppRichness = seq(min(sppRichness),
                                           max(sppRichness),
                                           length = 100),
                         # have to provide something for x and y
                         x = 1, y = 1))
p <- predict(gamFit, new data = newdf,
             exclude = "s(x,y)", # exclude the spatial effect from yhat
             type = "link", se.fit = TRUE)
newdf <- cbind(newdf, as.data.frame(p))
newdf <- transform(newdf,
                   upper = fit + (2*se.fit),
                   lower = fit - (2*se.fit))
```

As this is a Gaussian model you don't need to back transform to the response scale - if it was you'd need to apply the inverse of the link function to each of `fit`, `lower`, and `upper` before plotting.

The `exclude` argument to `predict.gam` allows you to generate predictions ignoring the listed term(s). Here we are doing what visreg is doing but we don't need to condition on a spatial coordinate. This might not go as close to the middle of the data are you might like, but that'll be because some of the response magnitude is removed from the smooth of `sppRichness` and is accounted for by the spatial term.

Comment: Thanks @Gavin! This is incredibly helpful. Would it be reasonable to say that what I get by plotting this is the relationship between the spRichness predictor and the response, without the influence of spatial autocorrelation?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "influence"; the smooth of `sppRichness` was estimated conditional upon the smooth of space, so space influenced the shape of the estimate smooth for `sppRichness`. But the plot is showing the effect of `sppRichness` on the response averaged over the effect of space, rather than being conditional upon some location